# Index.js is not importing App.js even when when export is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, web-development-server

Even though when I am using 'export default App;' there is still an error saying  './App does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').' in Index.js file. The error is solved when i change the name of the file.

this is the code in App.jsx file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import data from './data';
import Card from './Card'
import Heading from './Heading';
const App = () => {
const state = useState();
return (
<>
  <Heading />
  <div className="cards">
    {data.map((value, index) => {

      <Card
        cardimg={value.simg}
        cardname={value.sname}
        cardtitle={value.stitle}
        cardlink={value.links}
      />
    })
     }
   </div>
 </>
);
}
export default App;
```

and this is the code in index.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDom.render(
<App/>
,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

your const is Abhay this should be your export not App